# What is a canonical battery test that I can use before and after upgrading the OS version?

Tags: updates, battery, charging, battery-life

I am about to upgrade from Android K to Android L.
Right after, I will upgrade from Android L to Android M.

In a previous empirical experiment, with a now-demised device, I noticed (or seem to have noticed) that the battery life seriously degraded after upgrading Android.

Even after a good month of daily charging and discharging (from 0% to 100% and back), in the vain hope of properly recalibrating the battery, the lifetime was still down to about 8-10 hours from about 14-16 hours.

This time I would like to be able to prove it.

What is a canonical battery test that I can run (now and after upgrading) to determine whether upgrading deteriorated the battery life? I imagine that viewing a 6-hour YouTube video and noticing how far it goes would do the trick, but it's also very skewed to a single task. Is there an alternative that better represents the daily activities with an Android phone?

**Update:**

In addition to beeshyams's answer I'd like to point to Firelord's suggestion to use GSam, which does provide an ongoing "Averages Per Complete Charge".

[image: GSam screenshot]

Comment: Had your phone been rooted, I would have suggested to use [BetterBatteryStats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats). However, for now, perhaps, [GSam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsamlabs.bbm) can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now you would have long upgraded, but answering this hoping it may help anybody read it.

- "*What is a canonical battery test that I can run (now and after upgrading) to determine whether upgrading deteriorated the battery life?* Battery usage depends on so many parameters. The list is possibly endless but few examples are highlighted below, leading to the conclusion that designing a **canonical test is impractical** from end user point of view

  - **Device/ carrier specific** -CPU (frequency range, governor, number of cores) , GPU( frequency range, Mali blobs), screen (LCD, AMOLED and it's variants, brightness), network (2G,UMTS,3G,4G,LTE etc)
  - **Usage Specific** - activating sensors (like GPS, proximity which drain battery faster), social network apps which keep the device on always, type of sites visited and how long (plain text, multimedia), upload/download (also depends on host server traffic etc)
- Related to this, is that there seems to be **no standard definition that defines average use**. See my question [How is an "average use" defined in terms of battery life](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129677/how-is-an-average-use-defined-in-terms-of-battery-life). Answer to that question may help you in understanding how industry tests are carried out.
- *Even after a good month of daily charging and discharging (from 0% to 100% and back), in the vain hope of properly **recalibrating** the battery* - Battery calibration is a **myth**, see [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131545/bought-a-new-battery-do-i-need-to-calibrate-it)