# Bought a new battery, do I need to calibrate it?

Tags: battery, calibration

My original battery is bloated and is dying quickly after a full charge so I now bought a replacement. Do I need to calibrate this new battery using a calibration app?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No**

Calibration of batteries (Li Ion or Li Po, used in almost all mobile devices) is a myth

You can start using it straight away and charge as you normally did with earlier batteries

This post will help you understand more:

[Looking for a consistent answer about battery calibration](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50469/looking-for-a-consistent-answer-about-battery-calibration?s=1|1.8341)

Using calibration apps doesn't really help as the battery files in system (to which these apps write) are renewed and previous data erased when you charge / reboot

As explained in this [article](https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/FV3LVtdVxPT)

> It [*`Batterystats.bin` file which stores calibration information*] has no impact on the current battery level shown to you.
>   It has no impact on your battery life.......it is reset every time you unplug from power with a relatively full charge (thus why the battery usage UI data resets at that point)...

Explanation in Italics mine from the same article

---

### Related Myth : Charging a new battery for X hours

Charging a new battery for x hours before use is a "*legacy hangover*" from the days when Nickel Cadmium batteries were used. Those batteries had a "[memory effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_effect)". As a result, over a period of time, they "remembered" lesser battery capacity than rated capacity. To prevent this, it was advised to always fully charge these batteries

- This is not the case with Lithium Ion or Lithium polymer batteries. There is no logic to charge fully or x hours before use. Just use the battery normally, as suggested by others in comments
- [Table 1](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_charge_when_to_charge_table) corroborates with additional information

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a calibration app for that. Just fully charge the battery to 100% (in one run), let it run down to below the 20% mark, the recharge it to 100% (again in one run without interception) – battery calibrated.

And as that describes a "normal day" with recent devices (take it from the charger at 100% in the morning, put it back almost depleted in the evening): No calibration needed at all, you calibrate it as a side-effect :)

All those calibration apps do in addition is removing the `batterystats.bin` file – which doesn't do anything to calibrate the battery (an [old myth](http://www.xda-developers.com/google-engineer-debunks-myth-wiping-battery-stats-does-not-improve-battery-life/) in fact).