# Calibrating 2 batteries

Tags: battery

since I own 2 batteries for my G3 and one of them isn't working properly, I wanted to calibrate both of them. I've just calibrated my extended 5200 mAh battery and it seems like it lasts longer so I decided to calibrate another, original battery (3000 mAh). So my question is: Is it smart to calibrate 2 different batteries? Will calibrating one battery uncalibrate another one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Calibration is a myth. See this question to understand more [Bought a new battery, do I need to calibrate it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/131545/131553)

So it doesn't make any difference to one or two batteries- it has no affect on battery life or device