# Galaxy Note 4 turns off at about 15% remaining battery capacity

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, battery, battery-life, samsung-galaxy-note-4, calibration

I've been using my Note 4 for more than 2 years now and I'm absolutely happy with it, except for that one issue: the battery indicator on top does not match the *real* remaining capacity of the battery. The battery is still ok in terms of its "fitness", it usually allows for a whole day of (power) use. But it is annoying to see that the phone turns off at a shown power level of 13%, sometimes 16%. When I then plug in the charging cable, the charging screen shows the last level like 13%, but I think it *really* is 0%, because if I turn on the phone shortly after plugging the charger in, it turns off again before it completely boots up.

Is there a way to calibrate the battery level in such a way that the indicator gives correct resp. *useful* values again?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to calibrate the battery level in such a way that the indicator gives correct resp. *useful* values again?

**No** . Battery calibration is a myth and you can see this question for more. While the context of question is different, it answers why it is a myth
[Bought a new battery, do I need to calibrate it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/131545/131553)

- Li Ion batteries don't suddenly die ( unlike Ni Cd batteries ); their performance degrades **both** in terms of charge holding capacity and the performance or life per charge. Two years of usage is not really an indicator of battery life - it depends on a host of other things like how heavily it is used, how it has been charged etc. My gut feeling is that it has lived it's life and it's time more to replace the battery with a new one
- HTC and some Nexus devices have a way of fixing wonky battery readings using *battery reset logic*, but Samsung devices don't have this feature, so to fix it battery replacement is the first step. If the problem persists ( unlikely ) you may need to get it get it checked up

Comment: Thanks for your post. I don't mean to calbrate the battery but the *phone*, but it seems buying a new battery or living with the "sudden death" issue is my only option.

Comment: 1 Your phone or any phone can't be re- calibrated. Reason being that the battery state is monitored by a chip that resides in the battery. this information is read by the OS and displayed. There is always a possibility that OS is corrupted. To rule this out, you can do a factory reset or enter safe mode and see if the behaviour persists ( OS corruption is unlikely IMO) 2. As clarified in post, *sudden death* won't happen, it will gradually worsen in terms of performance. You will for sure have enough indications of poor performance and you can decide to replace battery later

Answer (score -2):

If you are rooted theres an app called "Battery calibrarion" which may help you.

What i didnt extract from your text: do you still use the original battery that came with a phone or one you bought somewhere else?

If you still use the original one,i recommend to buy a new one since batteries loose a certain percentage of their power after a long time.

Comment: Yes, it's the original one that came with the phone.

Comment: Well then i recommend to definetly buy a new battery. Besr case: all problems case. Worst case: your phones the problem

Comment: Even rooted apps don't have the ability to calibrate your battery. The app is fake.