# Change battery percentage at which phone turns off

Tags: settings, battery, battery-life

I'm trying to completely discharge an LG G2 D800 with Android 4.1; however, the phone always shuts down at 2%, so it's impossible for me to go down until the absolute zero. How could I change this configuration?

Comment: Calibration as recommended is an urban myth. Batteries lose capacity with time and usage and calibration doesn't help. What you are doing is actually harming the battery

Comment: @beeshyams Really? This is the first time I hear about it. Previously my friend's LG L70 experienced the same issue, I calibrated it and it's been working normally ever since. But the LG G2 won't let me do the full discharge.

Comment: See this https://android.stackexchange.com/q/131545/131553

Comment: That's weird because even the official LG support website recommends to calibrate the battery every 3 months (which is where I took the instructions I used for the other phone): http://www.lg.com/uk/support/solutions/mobile/battery-saver

Comment: Strange . Point 2 contradicts with what is to be done every 3 months. There is enough reasoning why that's bad. I wouldn't do that. Upto you

Comment: Lollipop upwards devices have shut down warning at 15 and 5%. Not without a reason

Comment: Well, regardless of that, the topic of this question is how to change that default percentage at which Android turns off. Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a "configuration". When the phone shuts off due to low battery, the battery is completely discharged. The shutting down isn't a configuration, it's due to the battery voltage dropping too low. The fact that the battery percentage displayed is above zero is just an artefact of the way the lifetime of the battery is estimated. The displayed percentage when the battery is discharged will gradually increase over the lifetime of the battery.

So if your aim is just to discharge the battery, you've already succeeded. Try not to do this too often, as full charge-discharge cycles reduce the lifespan of the battery.