# Battery shuts down at 25%

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life

I've read that battery calibration apps are only a placebo effect and they do nothing. Is this true? What to do if your phone suddenly shuts down at 25%?

Comment: Need new battery is most likely reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Battery calibration being a myth was asked here [Bought a new battery, do I need to calibrate it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/131545/131553) - incidentally by you :-), so yes to repeat, it's a myth (see Izzy's answer that stressed this)

To address shutting down at 25%:

- If the battery is old or heavily used I would first change the battery
- Check if the behavior persists in safe mode. If it does go to next step. If it doesn't it's caused by some app you installed (unlikely)
- Do [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset). If it continues, flash stock ROM (updated if available) or custom ROM
- If none of these help head to service center get an estimate and choose between repair or replacement of the device

Comment: Funny you're also in the old question :-)

Comment: Yes. I was waiting for you to say that :-)